# How to make ajax calls in codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter version 3.0.6 with HMVC Moduler Extension. (MX). When i try to make a ajax call it showing me a error massage 403.

```
<script>
var site = '<?=site_url()?>';
$('#item-name').keyup(function(){
     var d = $('#item-name').val();
     $('#item-list').css('display','block');
     $.post(site+"/moduleone/lists",{name: d}, function(data, status){
         $('#item-list').html(data);
     });
});
</script>
```

After executing this code i get and error in chrome console :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Module Method:

```
public function lists()
{
    echo 'afadfad';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: what is site_url()?

Comment: Codeigniter function echo `echo http://localhost/admin/index.php`

Comment: have you echo it? because in CI base url get using "base_url()" method

Comment: @B.Desai There are two method one is base_url() and site_url(). base_url() show `http://localhost/admin/` and site_url() show `http://localhost/admin/index.php`. I use PHP shortcut for echoing the method.

Comment: If you navigate to http://localhost/admin/moduleone/lists, does it say "afadfad" ???

Comment: @DannyThunder yes that work perfect but if i call it form ajax then it show that error

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I make codeigniter csrf true. That's why every time i submit a form it need a csrf token. But by the in ajax call there is no csrf token found that why it show the authentication error.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
    'moduleone/lists'
);
```

If you turn off (false the csrf_protection) then it work perfect.

if you want more information then check out the codeigniter user_guide.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `base_url()` and `site_url()` you have to load codeigniter `url` helper.Like this.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

or you can load it on `application/config/autoload.php`.Then make your `ajax` call like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    url = '<? echo base_url('moduleone/lists');?>';

    $('#item-name').on('keyup',function(){
         var d = $('#item-name').val();
         $('#item-list').css('display','block');

         $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:url,
            data: {name: d}, 
            success:function(data, status){
             $('#item-list').html(data);
            }
         });
    });
    });
</script>
```

And in Controller use `$this->input->post('name')` to get your name sent from ajax call. Like this.

```
public function lists()
{
    $name = $this->input->post('name');// name sent from ajax
    echo $name;

}
```

Comment: I already add helper url in autoloader. I tried your solution but the same problem.

Comment: Codeigniter application>modules>moduleone . In the folder moduleone their are three folder called controller,model,view.

Comment: did you set $_config['base_url'] in config.php?

Comment: try without keeping files in moduleone.i.e on default controller,model,view.